# Calculate Simple Moving Average

Tags: python

`data` is list containing candlestick objects. The `c`-property is the closing price of that candlestick.

I have the following Python code to calculate the SMA:

```
# Calculate to Simple Moving Average.
def sma(close_prices):
  return sum(close_prices) / len(close_prices)

def func(data):

  short_sma = 20
  long_sma = 100
  
  if len(data) <= long_sma:
    return 0
  
  close_prices = [d.c for d in data]
  
  sma_short = sma(close_prices[-short_sma:])
  sma_long = sma(close_prices[-long_sma:])
  
  if sma_short > sma_long:
    return 0.0005 # buy
  if sma_short < sma_long:
    return -0.0001 # sell
  
  return 0
```

I basically first put all the closing prices of the data list into a separate list called `closing_prices`. Then I indicate a long and short-window. The window is just the amount of candlesticks used to calculate the SMA.

The function `sma()` just sums up all the close prices and then divides it by the amount of datapoints, resulting in the average.

If the `short_sma` is bigger then the `long_sma` the stock is bullish and I return a positive number indicating a buy signal, otherwise a negative number is returned indicating a sell signal.

Is this the correct way to calculate the Simple Moving Average of a stock based on CandleSticks?

Comment: This looks like a reasonable implementation to me.

Comment: 2 Suggestions. 1) Don't hard code the `short_sma` and `long_sma`.  Make them optional parameters with default values. 2) The function `sma` is actually the mathematical average. Renaming it might be better for reader of the code.